Closure: 'What makes something relevant to an argument and how can people improve in determining relevance?'
Why was What makes something relevant to an argument and how can people improve in determining relevance? closed?
This comment states the question to concern relevance in logic, but I did not intend so?

Your first sub-question asks for, I quote: "1.What makes something (ir)relevant to an argument or discourse?"
This likely made people believe arguments and conclusions were your main focus which typically relies on logic (emotion, think Trump, being an alternative) and was deemed by those that voted to put this question on hold as off-topic more suitable for Philosophy SE.
If logic was not the perspective you were interested in, please clarify in the comments/question what is your desired perspective so that the question might be reopened.
